# Find the values of $ \ a,b \ $ so that the polyhedral set has extreme direction

Tags: linear-programming

Find the values of $ \ a,b \ $ so that the  polyhedral set defined by the system of inequalities

$$ ax+(b+1)y \leq 120 \\ x+(a+b)y \leq 160 \\ (a-b)x+y \leq 30 \\ x \geq 0 \\ y \geq 0 $$

**has extreme direction**.

**Answer:**

Does extreme direction means that we have to solve the equality as follows:

$$ ax+(b+1)y = 120 \\ x+(a+b)y = 160 \\ (a-b)x+y = 30 \\ x \geq 0 \\ y \geq 0 $$

If so then how to solve the $ \ 3 \ $ above equations ?

Any hints will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving for $x, y$

$$
ax+(b+1)y = 120\\
x+(a+b)y = 160
$$

giving

$$
x = \frac{40(3a-b-4)}{(a-1)(a+b+1)}\\
y = \frac{40(4a-3)}{(a-1)(a+b+1)}
$$

Now substituting $x(a,b), y(a,b)$ into $(a-b)x+y=30$ we have

$$
f(a,b)= 4b^2+9a^2-19b(1-a)-9=0
$$

which describes the variety obeying extreme direction. Except for some values ...

[image]

Attached the plot showing $x(a,b) > 0$ and $y(a,b) > 0$ in light blue and $f(a,b) = 0$ in red

Comment: what are the values of $ \ a , b \ $ ?

Comment: Do we have to maximize or minimize $ \ f(a,b) \ $ in order to have extreme direction ? And there we will get values of $ \ a, b \ $

Comment: All the pairs $(a,b)$ obeying $f(a,b) = 0$ and internal to the light blue region give extreme directions.